Is it possible to create a Power BI measure using a notebook in MS Fabric?
Currently, we have a warehouse in Fabric for which we would like to create measures using notebooks. As far as I know, measures can be created using the visual UI. Does anyone know if it is possible to do so using a notebook?

Yes.  You have access to the Tabular Object Model, and TMSL through semantic link, which is the python library for interacting with semantic models in Fabric notebooks.
EG
import sempy.fabric as fabric
from Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular import Measure 

svr = fabric.create_tom_server(readonly=False)

dbs = svr.get_Databases()

db = dbs.GetByName("DIAD Final Report with RLS")

model = db.get_Model()

tables = model.get_Tables()

tableName = "Sales"
measureName = "My New Total Sales"
measureExpression = "SUMX ( Sales, Sales[Revenue] * 1.1 )"

table = tables[tableName]

measures = table.Measures 

if measures.ContainsName(measureName):
    measures.Remove(measureName)

measure = Measure()
measure.Name = measureName
measure.measureExpression = measureExpression

measures.Add(measure)
result = model.SaveChanges()



Example adapted from: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/adding-a-measure-to-a-tabular-model/
